# get path to the children from parent

Tags: java, tail-recursion, n-ary-tree

I have a list of children and a list of parents. I also have a map of childeId-parentId. Parents can have n number of children but children have one immediate parent.
I want to get the path to each child from parent in Java. How can I do it recursively?

I have groups as: [Root, abc, asd, xyz, 123, xyz2]

parent-child map: {Root=abc, Root=asd, Root=xyz, Root=123, xyz=xyz2}

I want to get path of each child as:
{Root/abc, Root/asd, Root/xyz, Root/123, Root/xyz/xyz2}

I have a map :

`final<String, Groups> groupMap = Service.getListOfGroups(service);`

which gives me all the required values.
I am looping through the map to get each entry.

```
public Map<String, Groups> takeGroups(Service servie ) {
final<String, Groups> groupMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Groups gp: service.getGroups()){
groupMap.put(gp.getGroupId, gp)
}
for(Groups gp: groupMap.values()){
   gp.setChildren(new ArrayList<>());
   String group = gp.getGroupValue();
   String parentId = gp.getParent();
   Groups parentGroup = groupMap.get(parentId);
   List<GroupSummary> childs = parent.getChildren();
   if(childs == null){
      childs = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   childs.add(gd);
 } 
 return groupMap;
}
```

I think I can solve this by adding all these values to n-ary tree and then traversing through n-ary tree. I have never worked with trees before and not sure how can I create n-ary-tree from this and get the required paths to all the groups. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can please elaborate your question, show an example, show some of your code, etc. A good start would be: My parent list looks like X, my child list looks like Y, and my map looks like Z. Fill in the X,Y,Z with an example. Based on the example, show the path(s) you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.  Note that I have not tried to compile it, so it almost certainly has syntax errors.  But it should serve to give you an idea of what you have to do.

```
public List<Node> getPath( Node node, Map<Node,Node> childToParentMap )
{
    List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
    return fillPath( node, path );
}

private void fillPath( Node node, Map<Node,Node> childToParentMap, List<Node> path )
{
    Node parent = childToParentMap.get( node );
    if( parent != null )
        fillPath( parent, childToParentMap, path );
    path.add( node );
}
```

Comment: `Node* parent` ? Is your C++ leaking? :)

Comment: @HuguesMoreau C-:= I guess so!  (fixing...)

Comment: I have updated question. Can you please look at it. Thanks :)

Comment: You posted a nice, minimal, highly abstract question and I posted a nice, minimal, highly abstract answer.  I see no point in further complicating things now with `Map` of `String` to `Group` and `Service` and `ArrayList` of children and `parent.getChildren()`, which are all highly specific to your situation and of no interest to anyone else, and none of which was in your original question.